# How to write code IN VB6 SHAPE coding from 3 tables FOR DATA REPORT group heading

Tags: ms-access, vb6, shapes

```
nstring = "SHAPE {SELECT PRODUCTID,PRODUCTNAME FROM  PRODUCTMASTER } " & _
            "  APPEND ((SHAPE {SELECT * FROM ORDERDETAILS WHERE ORDERNO='" & 
"10001" & "' }" & _
            " APPEND ({SELECT PRODUCTID,ITEMCODE,ITEMNAME FROM ITEMDETAILS  }  
AS ORDITEMS RELATE " & _
            " PRODUCTID TO PRODUCTID,ITEMCODE TO ITEMCODE)) AS ORDERS RELATE 
PRODUCTID TO PRODUCTID)"
```

The above code in  "VB6 MS ACCESS DATABASE (ACCDB)  for data report . Group Header (Section 6) =  Productname

Details (Section 1 ) for all other fields including Itemname

But "itemname" showing error in Data report Section 1 as

> "Data Field orders.itemname not found "

Why does this occur?

Comment: You should make an effort to format this so it is readable.

Comment: Can you read now?